# add a textbox onclick dropdown value other in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am facing a problem with jquery.

I have a div with 4 drop down list and I have an "add more" button.

When I click on "add more" button, another instance of the same div is created just above the "add more" button. I did it via jQuery `append()` method and it is successfully working, but my problem is that the requirement says that when i select "Other" from the drop down a text box should open where I will fill the name which is not in the list.

I can do this but when i click on "add more" and another instance is created, When I select "other" from the dynamically created listbox the text box is not created because their id becomes same and I know that id can not be same.

Similarly, in rest of the dropdown happens. If i do it by class name then creates all the text box at a time. I do not want this.
I hope you understood my problem.
Please help me and give me a solution how to manage it.

Thanks everybody and thanks stackoverflow.com

**Update:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    alert('here'); 
    var content=$("#course").html(); 
    var content1=$("#emp").html(); 
    alert(content); 
    $("#add").click(function(){ 
        var n=$("#course .count").length; 
        if(n!=3){
            $("#course").append(content);
        }
        if(n==2){
            $("#add").hide();
        } 
    });
});
```

my html is like

dropdown1
dropdown1
dropdown1
dropdown1

add more button

when i select dynamically generated dropdown by append()...the textbox for 'other' not appears means unable to handle event on dynamically generated div thanks

Comment: It sounds like delegate would be the way to go here, but it's hard to tell without seeing any code. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
//alert('here');
var content=$("#course").html();
var content1=$("#emp").html();
//alert(content);
$("#add").click(function(){  
  var n=$("#course .count").length;
  if(n!=3){$("#course").append(content);}
  if(n==2){$("#add").hide();} 
});

Comment: can any body  tell me please how to post code thanks

Comment: Edit your question to post code, because comments ignore line formatting. You can then create blocks of code by adding 4 whitespaces in the beginning of your code. Or you can do `inline code` by including your code within the ` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you perhaps want something like this?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Scripttest</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var current = 1;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#addmore").bind('click', function() {
                $("#somediv").append(
                    $("<select/>").attr("id", current).attr("size", 1)
                        .append('<option value="someoption">Some Option</option>' +
                                '<option value="other">Other</option>')
                );
                $("<br/>").insertAfter($("#"+current));
                current++;
            });

            $("#somediv").delegate('select', 'change', function() {
                if($(this).val() == 'other') {
                    $("<textarea/>").attr("id", "tb_"+$(this).attr("id")).insertAfter($(this));
                }
                else {
                    $("#tb_" + $(this).attr("id")).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="addmore">Add more</button>
    <div id="somediv">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This would allow you to add dropdown lists and add a textarea behind it if the "Other" option is selected and remove it if it is deselected.

Comment: sir it is not working for the dynamically generated dropdown by append() method

Comment: @Shelim Ekbal It's not meant for copy/paste into your project, but rather to give you an idea of how to get it working. The magic is: when you dynamically insert elements into your page, and want event handling on these elements, your tool of choice is the `delegate()` function. I posted a link to the JQuery API in the comments of your question earlier. If you go through that, and take the example given in this answer as reference, you should be able to solve your problem.